# Has_one relationships and creating a new record in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following models, Member and Map, set up as so:

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_one :map, :dependent => :destroy
  ...
class Map < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :member
```

and my routes are set up with:

```
resources :members do
    resources :maps
end
```

and my maps controller is:

```
 def new
      @map = Map.new
  end

  def create
    @map = current_member.map.new(params[:map])

    if @map.save.....
```

But when I try to save a new map, I get an error `undefined method 'new'` on that create line. Im not sure why.

Comment: `current_member.map` will return `nil` if the member has no Map, and `nil` does not have a `new` method. You need to do what @Dmitry said.

Comment: `map` is not a reserved word? I think that's part of the problem in relation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference) is a description of all methods added by `has_one` association. You should use `build_map` for building a new map.